# load data local infile returns error, even though @@global.local_infile is 1

Tags: mysql, load, local, load-data-infile

I am trying to do a simple load data local infile statement but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

As mentioned in the title, if I run this:

```
select @@global.local_infile;
```

I get 1.

I am using mysql workbench, although the same thing happens when I use the command line.

Why does the load data local infile statement get an error?